# If $a = \frac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$ then $(a+1)^{25} =$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I have no idea how to do this.

> If  $a = \dfrac{\sqrt{5}+1}{2}$    then $(a+1)^{25} =$?

I tried to transform $a$ to polar form but failed, because if it can be in polar form, I could calculate with de Moivre's formulae.

Can anyone please explain me how to do this easily?

Thank you

Comment: Talking complex numbers, where is the $i$ ?

Comment: It's a positive real number, so polar form doesn't change anything.

Comment: maybe its $\sqrt{5}+i$?

Comment: Note that $a^2=a+1$, $a^3=2a+1$, $a^4=3a+2$, and so on... (Hint: Fibonacci numbers).

Comment: Approximately $28143753123$.

Answer (score 13):

Note that the number you are refering to is the [golden ratio](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Golden_ratio) $a=\phi=\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}$, and it is a solution to the equation 
$$\phi^2-\phi-1=0$$
thus rearanging we get 
$$\phi^2=\phi+1$$
multiply by $\phi$ to get
$$\phi^3=\phi^2+\phi=2\phi+1$$
and again
$$\phi^4=2\phi^2+\phi=3\phi+2$$
and again
$$\phi^5=3\phi^2+2\phi=5\phi+3$$
until you start to see the pattern of [Fibonacci numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fibonacci_number) in the coeficients, thus for any natural $n$
$$\phi^n=F_n\phi+F_{n-1}$$
where $F_n$ is the nth Fibonacci number.

Then, since $\phi^2=\phi+1$ we get that
$$(\phi+1)^{25}=\phi^{50}=F_{50}\phi+F_{49}$$

Answer (score 5):

**Hint:**

Note that 
$a^2=a+1$;
$a^3=2a+1$;
$a^4=3a+2$;
$a^5=5a+3$;
$...$
$a^n = F_{n}a+F_{n-1}$,

where $F_n$ is $n$-th Fibonacci number.